# How to remove the menu name from the action bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

How can I set a custom title for my action bar/toolbar ?

I am using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`.

Comment: What do you mean by "menu name"?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `AppTheme.NoActionBar` I think you're using a toolbar.

In your activity :

```kotlin
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
supportActionBar?.title = "My Title"
```